# show side bar menu open default in page load and close when click on toggle button in angular 4

Tags: jquery, html, css, angular

I am trying  to display sidebar menu open on page load event and close when user click on toggle button . please find below my component, css and html code.I am using Angular.how to show default sidebar menu on page load event and hide and show sidebar menu on toggle button click event.also sidebar menu Icons are not showing .find below my StackBlitz link:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rvaxeq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

```js
<!-- DashboardComponent.ts -->

toggleMenu(event) {
    console.log(event);
    $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
  }
```

```css
<!-- DashboardComponent.css -->
this is my css code which I am using for toggle sidebar menu.


   

#wrapper {
  padding-left: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#wrapper.toggled {
  padding-left: 250px;
}

#sidebar-wrapper {
  z-index: 1000;
  position: fixed;
  left: 250px;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: -250px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background: #34383e;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
  width: 250px;
}

#page-content-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  /*padding: 15px;*/
}

#wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  margin-right: -250px;
}


/* Sidebar Styles */

.sidebar-nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 250px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.sidebar-nav li {
  text-indent: 20px;
  line-height: 40px;
}

.sidebar-nav li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #999999;
}

  .sidebar-nav li a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    background: #4c5b6b;
  }

.sidebar-nav li a:active, .sidebar-nav li a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar-nav>.sidebar-brand {
  height: 65px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 60px;
}

.sidebar-nav>.sidebar-brand a {
  color: #999999;
}

.sidebar-nav>.sidebar-brand a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: none;
}

@media(min-width:768px) {
  #wrapper {
    padding-left: 0;
  }
  #wrapper.toggled {
    padding-left: 250px;
  }
  #sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 0;
  }
  #wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 250px;
  }
  #page-content-wrapper {
    /*padding: 20px;*/
    position: relative;
  }
  #wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 0;
  }
  
}
#menu-toggle {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: 700;
  height: 36px;
  line-height: 36px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<!-- DashboardComponent.html-->
this is my html code for sidebar menu.

<div id="wrapper">

  <!-- Sidebar -->
  <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
    <ul class="sidebar-nav">
      
      <li>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i>Administration</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->
  <!-- Page Content -->
  <div id="page-content-wrapper">
    <div class="container-fluid px-0">
      <div class="sidebar-submenu">
    <i id="menu-toggle" (click)="toggleMenu($event)" class="fas fa-bars"></i>
    
  </div>
      
     
        
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: add a stackblitz, it'll be easier to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`[ngClass]="{'toggled': show==true}"`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass)

[See working code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular4-pvo7bo?file=app/app.component.html)

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper" [ngClass]="{'toggled': show==true}">
```

**TS**

```
show:boolean=true;
//onclick
toggleMenu() {
this.show=this.show==false?true:false;
  }
```

**EDIT WITH CONTENT PAGE**

[See code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mz5dpl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css)

Comment: I have tried this

Comment: and??? whats your issuse?

Comment: <div class="sidebar-submenu" id="wrapper" *ngIf="show">
       <!-- <i id="menu-toggle" (click)="toggleMenu($event)" class="fas fa-bars"></i> -->
       <i id="wrapper" (click)="toggleMenu()" class="fas fa-bars"></i>   html---   show:boolean=true;
//onclick
toggleMenu() {
this.show=false       but it is not working toggle menu is showing on pageload and disappear after clicking

Comment: try my new edit(refresh the page) `<div id="wrapper" [ngClass]="{'toggled': show==true}">`

Comment: now only showing toggle menu

Comment: click on close on the side ber will toggle:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular4-pvo7bo?file=app/app.component.html

Comment: I want to show and hide on toggle menu click also in your code toggle "close" only working for hiding not working for  show and hide both .

Comment: OK see my edit please:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular4-pvo7bo?file=app/app.component.html

Comment: Please check my code sidebar menu list are not showing:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rvaxeq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mz5dpl?file=src/app/app.component.css

Comment: Please see my edited code I have to show "hello" when sidebar menu is visible: 
  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mz5dpl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mz5dpl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: how to make the page content responsive when sidebar menu is open means currently page content value is not visible when sidebar menu is showing :https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mz5dpl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Sidebar menu is overlapping on page content.

Comment: so decrease height ?? or what behavior do you want?

Comment: I want like this when side bar menu open : https://ibb.co/R0VBvv4

Comment: when side bar menu closed I want like this: https://ibb.co/rcnkpCm

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mz5dpl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css

Comment: Thanks finally it's working fine for me...

Comment: Thanks It's done